# Hover an specific element who have a parent element that has a pointer-events: none

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a container of my slider that have a pointer-events: none and I want to hover a paragraph in the card__content however that is not possible because I have a pointer-events: none on it's parent element. So I did try to have an hover in that specific element however it's not responding to what I stated in the css and why is that ?

Here the codepen https://codepen.io/marco-narca/pen/WNLwYPX

```js
const slider = document.querySelector('.container')
const cards = document.querySelector('.cards')
let saveValue = null;
let isPressed = false;
let cursorX;


function boundSlides() {
  const containerRect = slider.getBoundingClientRect();
  const cardsRect = cards.getBoundingClientRect();

  if (parseInt(saveValue) > 0) {
    saveValue = 0;
    cards.style.left = saveValue;
  } else if (cardsRect.right < containerRect.right) {
    saveValue = `-${cardsRect.width - containerRect.width}px`;
    cards.style.left = saveValue;
  }
}


slider.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  if (!isPressed) return;
  e.preventDefault();

  console.log(`Mousemove`);
  console.log(e);
  console.log(e.offsetX)
  console.log(cursorX);
  console.log(`Mousemove End`);

  saveValue = `${e.offsetX - cursorX}px`;
  cards.style.left = saveValue;
  boundSlides();
});

slider.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
  isPressed = true;
  console.log(`Mouse Down`);
  console.log(e.offsetX)
  console.log(cards.offsetLeft);
  console.log(`MouseDown End`);

  cursorX = e.offsetX - cards.offsetLeft;
  slider.style.cursor = "grabbing";
});

window.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
  console.log(`Mouseup!!!`);
  isPressed = false;
});
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: black;
}


/* global */

img {
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0.7rem 0;
}


/* container */

.container {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid green;
}


/*cards */

.cards {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 400px);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  pointer-events: none;
}


/* card */

.card {
  border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px 0px rgba(69, 67, 96, 0.2);
}


/* card_content */

.card__content {
  color: rgb(139, 137, 137);
  padding: 10px;
}

.card__content:hover {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cards">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT_X3kCeWYJuVS-vouoQhCfcRWKwbBX6RG1bA&usqp=CAU" alt="" />
      <div class="card__content">
        <h1>Coderpad</h1>
        <p>
          CoderPad is a simple yet powerful online technical assessment software that makes it easy to interview in the candidate's language of choice so hiring!
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR-jt3d-_xLuJFSQPmo6Tqepn4_wtLlgb9RHA&usqp=CAU" alt="" />
      <div class="card__content">
        <h1>Coderpad</h1>
        <p>
          CoderPad is a simple yet powerful online technical assessment software that makes it easy to interview in the candidate's language of choice so hiring!
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR-jt3d-_xLuJFSQPmo6Tqepn4_wtLlgb9RHA&usqp=CAU" alt="" />
      <div class="card__content">
        <h1>Coderpad</h1>
        <p>
          CoderPad is a simple yet powerful online technical assessment software that makes it easy to interview in the candidate's language of choice so hiring!
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess you can override this by setting ```pointer-events: auto;``` or ```pointer-event: all``` on the child element.